# How could the land departure be recorded when re-entering the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, i-94

I found the [following answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/depart-us-through-mexico-while-on-b1-b2-visitor-visa-how-us-will-know-i-did-no/38821#38821) for recording a land departure.
"A departure will be recorded if you depart via land and re-enter the United States prior to the expiration date stamped in your passport."
I wonder how the land departure could be recorded when re-entering the United States. Does it require some evidence? Please let me know it if there is any person who experienced this.

Comment: I am not a specialist of US immigration law at all and will let someone else answer but logic suggests that they can at least know you left, even if they don't know precisely when, simply because you present yourself from the other side of the border. That's probably why the text states “prior to the expiration date stamped in your passport”. It's only after that date that the exact date of departure becomes material.

Comment: A general advice (again not US specific) would be to keep as much evidence as possible (travel tickets, credit card receipts showing your presence in another country, foreign passport stamps) so you can support your version of events if challenged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires some explanation but it is not unusual. It was actually my toughest CBP interview so far (at about 2 minutes of questioning, so I wouldn't worry too much). Once the guy found the Canadian border entry stamp he seemed happy about it.

No documents or other information was sought from me, just a coherent explanation of how this had happened and about my travel plans. I was then re-admitted as normal for 90 days. No one has mentioned it since then but it comes up blank in my I94W travel history.

Please see also my answer to this question: [Exit stamp on passport when leaving US by bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50624/exit-stamp-on-passport-when-leaving-us-by-bus)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What's the meaning, " it comes up blank in my I94W travel history."? Does it mean that your departure record in I94W history is blank without any departure date?

Comment: @Peter No, the "departed from" field is blank, where it would normally show which port I used to exit (e.g., the one below says "NYC New York". The departure date was set to the date for my entry to Canada.